# Change the look of a website when inside an Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

It is possible to change the look of a website (say colours, width) when it is contained in a FRAME?

I am looking for some technique that is gonna work in all browsers.

Comment: I control both websites, if that is what you meant

Comment: What I am looking for is something to add to the website that will be displayed in the iFRAME.

Comment: It doesnt matter if you control both websites - if the page in the iFrame is on a different domain to the page which was loaded by the browser then you cant alter the content of the iFrame, from what I understand.

Comment: Of course since you control both websites, you can add code to the one which is loaded into the iFrame (ok ok I stated the obvious there..!). So if it is a theme you are looking to change, and that theme is stored in a stylesheet, then you can always tag a querystring (`?theme={themeName}`) onto the src of the iFrame. Then handle this in the iFrame src page to load a theme based on the querystring.

Comment: I think @ClarkeyBoy has the best idea, let the parent site pass the name of the theme in via query parameter and then let the child site use that variable.  Are these dynamic pages (php, asp.net or the like) or just straight html?  If straight html you can use jquery to parse the query string to get the values

Comment: @dstarh - I cant believe I didnt even think to ask if they were dynamic or static... I always kinda assume they will be dynamic as the majority of pages are these days. As far as I know jQuery, if the use of JavaScript is allowed, is pretty much the only option for static pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach mentioned at Wiki page dedicated to frame killers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller